# Is docker swarm loadbalancer enabled by default in traefik?

Tags: docker, traefik, swarm

I just need to know the answer on [this question](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/1779)

If it is disabled by default is there any option to enabled it on all backends without adding label "traefik.backend.loadbalancer.swarm=true" on every service?

Answer (score 0):

By exploiting a bug (issue 2138), I came to the conclusion that the default value is `false` (version v1.7.4).

I think you have to add that label for every service you use as an backend.

Take the example of enabling sticky session, in `traefik.toml`, you do:

```
[backends]
  [backends.backend1]
    # Enable sticky session
    [backends.backend1.loadbalancer.stickiness]
```

This is equivalent to add the following in the compose file,

```
  - "traefik.backend=backend1"
  - "traefik.backend.loadbalancer.stickiness=true"
```